# Force BT "headset" to use stereo on Windows 11?

Tags: bluetooth, windows-11, headset

Whenever I sync my Jabra 65t earphones to my Windows 11 laptop, they successfully sync. When playing media immediately after syncing, for a short time the audio will be at full quality, then cut for a second, then play at a very reduced quality, sounding echoey/underwater. This is then permanent across multiple reconnections and restarts until the devices are hard-resynced. It will happen on this laptop and not on an Android phone, I have not tried any other devices.

After looking up the issue, I have come to the understanding that this is a limitation with Bluetooth "headsets", it can only either use stereo for high quality output or hands-free for low quality output and input.

Since I am happy to just not use the microphone on the earphones on this device, it would be sufficient for me to just disable the hands-free mode and force stereo, however, I can find no way to successfully do this. Notably, Windows only lists 1 output device, whereas I have seen other posts showing Windows listing one for stereo and one for hands-free. Following various other posts and suggestions, I have tried:

- Disabling the only output device from the dedicated sound menu disables the output entirely. Disabling the input only stops the microphone from working.
- Disabling "Handsfree Telephony" in the control panel removes the input, but does not improve output quality.
- Reinstalling, removing or disabling various items relating to the earphones in Device Manager will either do nothing or disable the input or output, but not affect output quality.

Also, most of these things have been tried with the only call software installed, Discord, both open and closed, so I don't think this is affecting the device. Any assistance in what should be a simple endeavour would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that despite the way it seemed, the issue was NOT Bluetooth, instead a unique issue with the MaxxAudioPro tool apparently installed on my device already. Changing the preset in this tool to "office" seems to have tentatively fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 11:

Control panel - Sound

Select "Recording" tab

Find your headset on the list, right click, and "Disable".

You might need to wait a few secs before windows applies it. Afterwards the BT headphone works again in stereo - but you cannot use it as a headset any more.

Comment: Based on the answer OP gave, I'm guessing you have a different problem, and this is not the solution to the question that was asked here.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1133957)